# Несколько таблиц MySQL одним запросом SQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Друзья подскажите как можно одним запросом `SQL` создать несколько таблиц. Без использование `PHP ООП`.У меня есть такой пример кода. Подскажите  как можно  решить проблему.Заранее спасибо

Вот код

```
<?php  

if (isset($_POST['connect'])){

     $dbhost=htmlentities($_POST['dbhost']);
     $dbuser=htmlentities($_POST['dbuser']);
     $dbpass=htmlentities($_POST['dbpass']);
     $dbname=htmlentities($_POST['dbname']);

$connection=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

if(!$connection){
     die("No Connection" .mysqli_connect_error());
 }
      else{
         echo "connection Sucesfully";
     }

$sql="
 CREATE TABLE languages (
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
rus TEXT(200) NOT NULL,
eng TEXT(200) NOT NULL,
pl  TEXT(200) NOT NULL
),
 CREATE TABLE gallery (
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
big_img     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
middle_img  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
small_img   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)";
    if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    echo "All Tables Created Successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($connection);
}

mysqli_close($connection);

}


?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
</body>

<form  action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"  method="post">

<input type="text" name="dbhost"  placeholder="Enter Host Name">
</br>
<input  type="text"  name="dbuser" placeholder="Enter Database User Name">
</br>
<input type="password"  name="dbpass"  placeholder="Enter Database Password">
</br>
<input  type="text" name="dbname"  placeholder="Enter Database Name">
</br>
<button type="submit" name="connect"  value="send">Connect Database</button>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Замените запятую на точку с запятой - `$sql="
 CREATE TABLE languages (
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
rus TEXT(200) NOT NULL,
eng TEXT(200) NOT NULL,
pl  TEXT(200) NOT NULL
);
 CREATE TABLE gallery (
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
big_img     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
middle_img  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
small_img   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)"`

Comment: Одним запросом на создание таблицы можно создать только одну таблицу. Но если под "запросом" понимать вызов хранимой процедуры, или отправку нескольких запросов одним пакетом (одним оператором - если коннектор позволяет) - то да, возможно.

Comment: PS. `mysqli_query` этого не умеет. А вот `mysqli_multi_query` - запросто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала запросы нужно разделить символом `;`, а потом использовать функцию `mysqli_multi_query()`

```
$sql="
 CREATE TABLE languages (
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
rus TEXT(200) NOT NULL,
eng TEXT(200) NOT NULL,
pl  TEXT(200) NOT NULL
);
 CREATE TABLE gallery (
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
big_img     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
middle_img  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
small_img   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);";
    if (mysqli_multi_query($connection, $sql)) {
    echo "All Tables Created Successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

Ну и да, обычно таблицы создаются не из PHP, а путем импорта дампа базы

Comment: Спасибо за ответ .Можно узнтаь какое максимальное количество запросов    для  функции mysqli_multi_query

Comment: Количество запросов не ограничено. А общий размер всех запросов ограничен переменной MySQL `max_allowed_packet`